# MacBook: 12-channel phono output to speakers

Tags: audio, speakers

I need to output audio from my MacBook on 12 channels, independently, to 12 mono speakers.

I need speakers to be lightweight so that they can be worn on a hat (it is a surround-sound type experiment).

I will be playing piano notes from the speakers, and the frequency of A0, the lowest note,  is ~27.5Hz, so I think this rules out piezo.

I don't need a high fidelity response, but the note does need to be recognisable.

What are my options?

Can I use power from the USB soundcard?

EDIT: hmm  migrated from the electronics Forum :|   I don't get it... I'm asking a question about speaker technology, which is an electronics question. But anyway, I am grateful for any input.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why 12 speakers?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some custom hardware to pull this off. 12-channel USB sound cards do not exist, so you will have to develop your own, including drivers.

Interesting project though. Sounds cool :)

May be worth a KickStarter to raise some money to pay a DSP developer.